# error : is a field but used as a type

Tags: c#-4.0

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication5
{
    public class ClientContext
    {
        private string p;

        public ClientContext(string p)
        {
            // TODO: Complete member initialization
            this.p = p;
        }
    }

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


    //First construct client context, the object which will be responsible for
    //communication with SharePoint:
        private ClientContext context = new ClientContext("@url"); 


    //then get a hold of the list item you want to download, for example
    public List list;
        public ClientContext
        {
           list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("001_CFR_DPV_COST_REV_SHARING");
        }

    //note that data has not been loaded yet. In order to load the data
    //you need to tell SharePoint client what you want to download:

    context.Load(result, items=>items.Include(
        item => item["Title"],
        item => item["FileRef"]
    ));

    //now you get the data
    context.ExecuteQuery();

    //here you have list items, but not their content (files). To download file
    //you'll have to do something like this:

    var item = items.First();

    //get the URL of the file you want:
    var fileRef = item["FileRef"];

    //get the file contents:
    FileInformation fileInfo = File.OpenBinaryDirect(context, fileRef.ToString());

    using (var memory = new MemoryStream())
    {
          byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 64];
          int nread = 0;
          while ((nread = fileInfo.Stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
          {
              memory.Write(buffer, 0, nread);
          }
          memory.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
          // ... here you have the contents of your file in memory, 
          // do whatever you want
    }
    }
}
```

this is the complete code.
I don't know why it is showing error. I searched for the error "is a field but used as a type" and I tried that but it didn't help. Please help with a solution Code to this since I am new to this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I am sorry to have to say this; but either the code you pasted went wrong, or there are multiple serious errors in there. I have to assume it is the last option. In that case it would be best to start with a basic C# tutorial and fin out for yourself why this is wrong.

Comment: There are many syntax errors and your code won't build at all.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Calling a list including those columns? Then! I guess you should update your question as the title doesnt match the description.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve by this lines of code?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    ...
    public ClientContext
    {
       list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("001_CFR_DPV_COST_REV_SHARING");
    }    
}
```

What is `public ClientContext {}` inside class Form1 ?

It seems that you intended to create constructor to a class in another class and for compiler it looks more like a property but without accessors (get, set) as if it is a Type or smth like this.

Try to put get; set; accessors inside if you intended to create property:

```
public List Context
{ 
   get 
   { 
       list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("001_CFR_DPV_COST_REV_SHARING");
       return list;
   } 
}
```

Or change it to method instead :

```
   public void GetClientContext()
   {
      list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("001_CFR_DPV_COST_REV_SHARING");
   }
```